# How do I remove duplicate rows based on two Columns? (E.g. A Pair Value Set)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Here is my Query in SQL Server...

```
SELECT hs.NAME   Highschooler, 
        hs.grade  inGrade1, 
        hs2.NAME  likes, 
        hs2.grade inGrade2 
FROM    highschooler hs 
        JOIN likes l ON hs.id = l.id1 
        JOIN highschooler hs2 ON hs2.id = l.id2
```

I get

```
    HIGHSCHOOLER   INGRADE1  LIKES      INGRADE2
1-----Cassandra        9    Gabriel         9
2-----Gabriel          9    Cassandra       9
3-----Andrew           10   Cassandra       9
4-----John             12   Haley           10
5-----Brittany         10   Kris            10
6-----Alexis           11   Kris            10
7-----Gabriel          11   Alexis          11
8-----Kyle             12   Jessica         11
9-----Austin           11   Jordan          12
10----Jessica          11   Kyle            12
```

I want to remove the paired duplicates from the column HIGHSCHOOLER and LIKES...

like in the table above
the **8th** and **10th** rows have the same pair **(kyle - jessica)** and **(Jessica - kyle)** i.e duplicate pair and **i want to remove that duplicate**

This is the link of the question that i faced..
https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/DB/SQL/SelfPaced/courseware/ch-sql/seq-exercise-sql_social_query_core/

i think u should get registered to get the questions

and in the marked section and the marked question
[image: In the marked section and in the **Q3 question** i get the scenario]

[image]

and the link for the database 
https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/DB/SQL/asset/socialdata.html

Comment: Remove duplicates means that you only want to keep one row for each or that you want to remove all?

Comment: Just because I like the girl next door, does not mean she likes me. (A likes B is different from B likes A.)

Comment: Yes you are right @Tim Schmelter i just want only one pair of that duplicate pair and remove others which do not have a duplicate pair like **(Alexis - Kris)** dont have a duplicate pair where as  **(kyle - jessica)** has a duplicate pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to leave data, because Cassandra likes Gabriel and Gabriel likes Cassandra are different actions. So I will suggest the following query:

```
WITH cte AS(SELECT hs.NAME Highschooler ,
                   hs.grade inGrade1 ,
                   hs2.NAME likes ,
                   hs2.grade inGrade2 ,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN l.id1 < l.id2 THEN l.id1 
                                                        ELSE l.id2 END,
                                                   CASE WHEN l.id1 < l.id2 THEN l.id2 
                                                        ELSE l.id1 END 
                                      ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
             FROM  highschooler hs
             JOIN likes l ON hs.id = l.id1
             JOIN highschooler hs2 ON hs2.id = l.id2)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
```

This is the demostration:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( id1 INT, id2 INT )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 2 ),
        ( 2, 1 ),
        ( 1, 3 ),
        ( 5, 6 ),
        ( 6, 5 ),
        ( 7, 8 );
WITH cte AS(SELECT * ,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN id1 < id2 THEN id1 
                                                        ELSE id2 END,
                                                   CASE WHEN id1 < id2 THEN id2 
                                                        ELSE id1 END 
                                      ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
            FROM @t)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
```

Output:

```
id1 id2 rn
1   2   1
1   3   1
5   6   1
7   8   1
```

Comment: sorry @Giorgi Nakeuri i'm newbie to SQL i'm unable to get some of the KEYWORDS in your QUERY like the DECLARE ,WITH,CASE  ,PARTITION can you simplify  the query to just simple SQL query

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the duplicates from `likes`.  One method is to use `union all` (and this is probably the fastest method if you have an index on `likes(id1, id2)`).  You can do the removal before doing the `join`:

```
SELECT hs.NAME as Highschooler, hs.grade as inGrade1, hs2.NAME as likes, hs2.grade as inGrade2 
FROM (select l.id1, l.id2
      from likes l
      where l.id1 < l.id2
      union all
      select l.id1, l.id2
      from likes l
      where l.id1 > l.id2 and
            not exists (select 1 from likes l2 where l.id2 = l2.id1 and l.id1 = l2.id2)
     ) l join
     highschooler hs
     ON hs.id = l.id1 JOIN
     highschooler hs2
     ON hs2.id = l.id2;
```

Comment: "not exists (select 1 from likes l where l.id2 = **l2.id1** and l.id1 = **l2**.id2)" which one is the **l2** table there is no l2 here. and when  i execute the above query i m not getting the desired result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT hs.NAME   Highschooler, 
        hs.grade  inGrade1, 
        hs2.NAME  likes, 
        hs2.grade inGrade2 
FROM    highschooler hs 
        JOIN likes l ON l.id1 = hs.id   + 1
```

Comment: there is no **hs2** Table in the join please correct it and explain the code

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure that there's duplicate for every like, then you can remove duplicates like this

```
;with cte_likes as (
    select l.id1, l.id2
    from likes as l
    where
        not exists (select * from likes as l2 on l2.id1 = l.id2 and l2.id2 = l.id1) or
        l.id1 < l.id2
)
SELECT hs.NAME   Highschooler, 
        hs.grade  inGrade1, 
        hs2.NAME  likes, 
        hs2.grade inGrade2 
FROM    highschooler hs 
        JOIN cte_likes l ON hs.id = l.id1 
        JOIN highschooler hs2 ON hs2.id = l.id2
```

and if you have duplicates in `likes` table for every record, then you can do it like this

```
SELECT hs.NAME   Highschooler, 
        hs.grade  inGrade1, 
        hs2.NAME  likes, 
        hs2.grade inGrade2 
FROM    highschooler hs 
        JOIN likes l ON hs.id = l.id1 
        JOIN highschooler hs2 ON hs2.id = l.id2
where
    l.id1 < l.id2
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer with just simple joins with nested condions for the question

```
 select 
       h1.name, 
       h1.grade, 
       h2.name, 
       h2.grade  
from 
       Likes l1, Likes l2, Highschooler h1, Highschooler h2
where 
       l1.ID1=l2.ID2 and 
       l2.ID1=l1.ID2 and 
       l1.ID1=h1.ID and 
       l1.ID2=h2.ID and 
       h1.name<h2.name
```